# YAMAHAルーター（RTX810）でメールが送れない

Tags: network

ヤマハルーター（RTX810）にてメール送信機能について、質問です。

RTX810から契約しているISPのSMTPサーバよりメールを送信したいのですが、現在、下記のエラーにより送信ができない状況です。

◆エラー内容：
Mail IO Service Is Timeout(mail: 60 sec)

◆設定：
・ISP（J:COM）よりいただいた契約書に記載のあるSMTPサーバ、ポート、ユーザID、パスワード、ポート番号（465番）を下記のコマンドで設定しました。

//テンプレ設定
mail server name 1 test
//SMTPサーバ設定
mail server smtp 1 [SMTPサーバアドレス] smtp-auth [USERNAME] [PASSWORD] digest-md5
//送信メールのテンプレ設定
mail template 1 1 From:[送信元メアド] To:[送信機メアド] Subject:test
//トリガー設定
mail notify 1 1 trigger status all

◆実行内容
//メール送信コマンド
mail notify status exec 1
//ログ確認
show log reverse

上記を実行まで実行すると下記のように表示。
Mail IO Service Is Timeout(mail: 60 sec)

SMTPサーバにnslookupとpingできる疎通は問題ないかと思います。ちなみに、NW構成は、ホームゲートウェイの下にRTX810配置しており2重ルーターですが、上記の通り、インターネット接続は可能です。

SMTPサーバのタイムアウトエラーの原因、解決方法がわかる方がいらっしゃいましたらご教示いただけると幸いです！

Comment: ポートが設定されてないようですが

Comment: mail server smtp 1 [smtp.example.com] port=465 smtp-auth [userID] [Password] と設定しても同様でした。。（port=587も確認済み）RTX810ですとsmtpsなどの暗号化が施せないようですが、こちらがエラー原因の可能性もあるんですかね？